# Changing the default folder in django-static

Tags: django, django-static

I am looking at using django-static for serving the static content
(https://github.com/peterbe/django-static)

But django-static always assumes that all the "static content" is always placed in "media" folder. Can I configure this to be a different folder?

I checked the configuration options but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Static file processing is [built into django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). Suggest you use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it uses `MEDIA_ROOT` setting to find source files.

From its documentation

**By default django_static will look for source files in MEDIA_ROOT, but it is possible tell django_static to look in all directories listed in DJANGO_STATIC_MEDIA_ROOTS. The first match will be used.**